# Moga gamepad not working with A-Frame

Tags: aframe, gamepad-api

I have a Moga Pro gamepad that I am trying to use with A-Frame.  According to the A-Frame 0.5.0 docs on tracked-controls, I should be able to add something like:

```
<a-entity tracked-controls="controller: 0; idPrefix: Moga"></a-entity>
```

and I would be able to use my gamepad.  But the above code doesn't work.

Also, I am running a [gamepad test](https://github.com/luser/gamepadtest) on a local server that identifies my controller as

```
gamepad: Moga Pro 2 HID (STANDARD GAMEPAD Vendor: 20d6 Product: 6271)
```

Do I need to do something else in the A-Frame code to make the gamepad work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tracked-controls` component is for 6DOF tracked controllers, and won't support arbitrary gamepads. You probably want to try [`universal-controls`](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls) or [`gamepad-controls`](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-gamepad-controls) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I used <a-entity camera gamepad-controls look-controls wasd-controls> with aframe-gamepad-controls.js and that did the trick!